# How does one include sign language in a dialogue?

Tags: fiction, dialogue, formatting, language

If one character is using sign language and lip reading while the other is speaking normally, how do you represent the lines of the former? Quotations with "he signed" attribution or italics? E.g.

> "When did you first feel the pain?" asked the doctor.
>
> *Two days ago,* signed the patient.

Comment: Okay, I have to ask.  If the doctor is relying on the signer's lip reading ability to be understood, I assume he doesn't understand sign language.  So why does patient sign their response?

Comment: Er, it's the other way around. It's the *patient* who is lip reading (because the doctor only knows sign language enough to understand a few simple phrases). Some people who use sign language do it habitually even when the other person is not proficient in it.

Comment: Per both answers, *italics* is a quick and easy way to do it. But if there's going to be a lot of this type of dialogue, you might consider using a distinctive font for the signed communications. And as a rule use a clarifying verb like "signed, indicated, gestured" for the first one in an interchange whenever it's been several pages since the last one. After that, use non-specific verbs like "suggested, replied, answered" and avoid verbs "said". But you might get away with the occasional "shouted" or similar in a metaphorical sense (perhaps in quotes to alert the reader to what you're doing).

Comment: I understand that is the patient who is lip-reading and signing.  That's why I don't understand why he is responding in sign, the doctor is not going to understand (unless "two days ago" is one of the few phrases he understands).  If he is doing sim-com (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_Communication), then that is whole different ball of wax and needs to be addressed in a different way. Or are you saying that he responded in Sign on accident, and the next line of your example would be him correcting himself in English?

Comment: @JoelShea In the actual scene (this is just a dummy) the signing makes a little more sense. The deaf character has no other means to communicate with the other person under the circumstance. I'll take SimCom into consideration, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In my experience, using anything other than a monospaced font with just italics in a manuscript is a good way to annoy the editor!

Comment: @HNL: I have no experience of submissions to editors, and I don't expect that to change, since I don't do creative writing. But if I *did*, I'd expect to do it on my own terms - if the editor didn't like my font, I'd either find another one who wasn't so hidebound, or just forget about editors and publish myself directly onto the net. Whatever - I was only trying to help. One can't help but notice that books from established authors use fonts creatively in this way when the need arises, and it seems insane that the author can't write directly in them. Jobsworth for later typesetters, perhaps?

Comment: It would also depend on how important the signing part is to the story. If you want to emphasize that aspect vs. if it's just the logical step in your story. I've seen HOH people say that the emphasis on signing in fiction sometimes makes them uncomfortable.

Comment: Personally, I like to denote any spoken (or signed) language with a character set that opens and closes but is not quotation marks (I like "less than/ greater than" characters "<Dialoge>".   I use this as a short hand to let the readers know that the speakers are using this English phrase correctly translated into the language they are actually speaking.   I know that ASL lacks articles (a, an, the) so while I would use them in an english sentance, the actual signed message isn't necessarily that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Italics make sense when sign is not the language most of the dialogue is in (I think this is a common tactic for "secondary" languages).  But if sign is the main language in your piece, I would just put it in quotes like any other dialogue.

I guess the only question I would have for you is what is the main language of the dialogue?  If it's sign language, I wouldn't give it second class treatment in italics.

Comment: The main language versus occasional language point is key.  Too many italics will clutter the page visually.

Comment: The main language is indeed English, or in the case of the actual dialogue that I'm writing, a common interplanetary language (the actual scene is a spaceship captain meeting a large, deaf man with a battle axe) :-)

Comment: So, I'd look to set your sign language in quote marks, but with some other character that can open and close.  Since it's a scifi setting, it's useful in that you might have alien languages that you want the readers to know but not the characters.   Think like a subtitled foreign language in a film or tv show.

Comment: No, don't ever put signed dialogue in quotes. Quotes are the explicit convention for spoken language. Sign language is not spoken, but signed. Don't confuse the reader by representing it as something it is not. Use italics and nothing else. Italics are not "second class treatment" but markup that has meaning. If you want to represent sign language as what it is, use illustrations of signing hands. If you represent sign dialogue as words, then the words are a ***translation*** like a translation from a foreign language. You are translating signs into words for the reader. Markup accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, italics is exactly how I'd do it. Dean Koontz did that in *Watchers,* as I recall.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use normal text set off by "guillemets", which are symbols used in some other languages instead of quotation marks. See the Wikipedia article 'Guillemet'. There are several styles, e.g. with or without extra spaces, with the guillemets pointing inwards » « instead of outwards, « » etc.

It would look like:

"Hi Dave."

« Good morning Sarah. »

This is distinctive, and wouldn't use italics for another meaning in addition to emphasis, thought that are not spoken out loud, etc.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to actually writing the signer's line, I tend to write them between apostrophes. I find it easier and a little more visually appealing than italics, but still allows the reader to differentiate the two languages. I more commonly save the italicization for internal thoughts.

'I wish I could go to the park.'  vs.  *I wish I could go to the park.*

Answer (score 2):

I find italics to be easier to understand as the reader. It makes it less complicated and can be caught by the eye pretty rapidly and the reader will learn to recognize the person's dialogue by the italics. It's just overall a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Sign language is not merely a representation of English with signs but a language of its own. For a brief introduction refer to the section on [the relationship between sign and spoken languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_language#Relationships_with_spoken_languages) in the Wikipedia article on sign languages.

Therefore, if you represent sign language in an English text, the English words are in fact a translation from a different language. Treat it as such. Specifically:

1. If all (or most) characters in your text communicate in sign language, use quotes.

   Think of a book written in English but set in France with the characters speaking French. For the sake of your English readers you will render all dialogue in English, as if the characters were speaking English. Do the same when the story is set in a community of signing persons who use sign language to communicate.
2. If most of your chacters communicate in English most of the time and sign language is the exception, markup the English representation of sign language as italics.

   Non-spoken language – such as written text or speech from a device (e.g. radio) – are conventionally marked up as italics. Sign language is not spoken, so use the markup for non-spoken languages.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make the most sense to use the primary language in quotations, because as the previous answer stated, using too many italics would end up making the literature seem cluttered.